# $N^L$ vs. ${N+L\choose N}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Any ideas on finding a good estimate/approximation for $\frac AB$ where $A = N^L$ and $B = {N+L\choose N}$?

Comment: You could try applying Stirling on the factorials implicit in the binomial coefficient...

Comment: I don't understand the notations $N^L$ and $C_{N+L}^N$. What do those mean?

Comment: @Mitch:  I am taking $N^L$ as the exponential and $C_{N+L}^N$ as the binomial coefficient of $N+L$ choose $N$

Comment: In what regime? If $L$ is fixed and $N$ is allowed to grow then the ratio approaches $L!$.

Comment: Wow, just the slightest change in notation (from lower case to upper) made me misunderstand. That's not a problem with the notation, but a problem with my reading ability.

Comment: Well actually $N$ and $L$ are fixed and less than 100. Thanks for pointing to Stirling's approximation, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you expand $B$ as $\frac{(N+L)!}{N!L!}$ and then use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) on the factorials, you will be very close.

Answer (score 3):

$\log(A/B) = \log(L!) - \sum_{j=1}^L \log(1+j/N)$.  You can approximate or bound the sum in various ways, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that by $C_{N+L}^N$ you mean the binomial coefficient $(N+L)!/N!L!$. (I would denote this by ${N+L \choose N}$.)

If you're thinking of $L$ as a constant then you can write this as

$$ {(N+L)(N+L-1) \cdots (N+1) \over L!}. $$

And you can expand out the numerator; you get

$$ {(N^L + {L(L+1) \over 2} N^{L-1} + \cdots) \over L!} $$

Comment: Thank you, this is a good hint as well.